# Change of variable in double integral. Domain transformation.

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

$$\iint_D(\frac{y^2 - x^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2})dxdy $$
$$D = {(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2<1}$$
Could you please help me? I tried to apply the transformation to polar coordinates and yet I don't know how to transform the domain correctly.

Comment: I'd first do a translation to have the origin in $(1,1)$. Anyway you can just substitute $x=r\cos t, y=r\sin t$ and expand in the expression of the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $x\to y$ and $y\to x$, one has
$$ \iint_D\frac{y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}dxdy=\iint_D\frac{x^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}dxdy $$
and heence
\begin{eqnarray}
\iint_D\frac{y^2 - x^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}dxdy=0.
\end{eqnarray}